# How to repair cassandra. I am not sure how to use the nodetool after changing snitch

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

I am an intern with not much experience so I am sure you guys can help me out here a bit. I get all types of nodetool syntax from google and I am not sure how to use it and when i should use it.
My 3 node cluster was only showing 1 node on the ring. So i changed the snitch to rackInferring and restarted cassandra. Now do I have to run nodetool repair? How?

Answer (score 2):

I am concerned that `nodetool ring` isn't seeing all of your nodes. Fix that first before running `nodetool repair`. Otherwise, `nodetool repair` has no other nodes to talk to and will not completely correctly.

To get your ring intact, make sure all of your nodes are configured to talk gossip on the same network. Make sure they all have at least one seed node which is configured the same on all nodes and is up. Make sure they all have the same cluster name. If that fails, bring them all down and then bring them back up one by one.